# UTF-16 (LE) byte order mark detected

Tags: xcode

I got the following error when I've made a Mac App.

> UTF-16 (LE) byte order mark detected in '/Users/yanagisawa_yuma/Documents/oF/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/apps/myApps/ArtHackSound/src/ofApp.cpp', but encoding is not supported

Obviously, this is related to encoding issues, but I do not understand how to fix it.

Comment: I just copied the project and it works fine then.
However, it is not so smart.

Comment: Unfortunatly there was never a rule on including a BOM so with or without is acceptable. Blame the BE vs LE wars. UTF-8 does not suffer from this issue.

Comment: Using Sublime and File -> Save With Encoding -> UTF-8 worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem in Mac. I installed the **dos2unix** utility and just converted the file. It fixed the problem.

```
neo-mac:random_experiments$ dos2unix graph/FindIsland.cpp
dos2unix: converting UTF-16LE file graph/FindIsland.cpp to UTF-8 Unix format...
```

Answer (score 1):

@raven is right.
But you maybe not modify it right at first time.

[You can first choose UTF-16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KM5Ce.jpg)

[and then convert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC8Su.jpg)

finally,choose UTF-8 ,and convert

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Try to modify Test Encoding to    Unicode(UTF-8)